# Are there search tools for answers?

Tags: support, feature-request

I have answered quite a few questions and what is bothering me more and more is that there are **no search tools** to sift through my **answers**. Some new questions overlap to some extent with old, answered questions and I really need some tools to sift through my answers now and then to look them up. Also, it happens now and then that I think a new question is a duplicate question, because I believe to have answered a similar question, but I simply can't efficiently look back through my answers list to identify the suspected duplicate question.

It would be awesome to be able to **filter my answer list** using a specific **tag**. When searching for questions, this feature exists, but does it exist for sifting through one's own (or another user's) answers (and perhaps questions)?

Are there perhaps tricks in Google to sift through answers of a specific user on a specific SE site?

Comment: The [help page for advanced search](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/searching) will solve all of your problems. Clicking 'Advanced Search Tips' at the top right of your page of search results will also give a short summary of search options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an easy one!

Under Activity on your profile, click on the tags menu:

[image]

Then from there click on any one of the tags you are interested in and it will show you only your posts related to that tag.

Another way to accomplish the same thing is to use your user id and the tag you are interested in in the search box, so if you did

```
user:9943 [neuroscience] action potential
```

you would get the 31 results of questions and answers about neuroscience that were about action potential that you posted.

```
user:9943 [neuroscience] action potential is:answer
```

you would get the 29 results of only *answers* about neuroscience that were about action potential that you posted.

Comment: Holy smokes!! ***awesomeness*** :-D

Comment: @Christiaan It's not like I am stalking you or anything... just showing you how to use the tools. :-)

Comment: and *much* appreciated it is :)

Comment: You can also use 'user:me' in the search field for any search directly